# ZF2 Routes - The requested URL could not be matched by routing

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I'm having trouble setting up a route for a very simple controller.  I'm getting the "The requested URL could not be matched by routing." error.  I've viewed similar solved questions on SO and can't pinpoint what I'm doing wrong (Ex: [ZF2 - Zend Framework 2, understanding routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280087/zf2-zend-framework-2-understanding-routing))

I've followed the [skeleton tutorial with the albums](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html) subject and everything functioned perfectly fine.  I tried duplicating the album module and then changing the name of the controller, folder, module config, etc.  I figured this would be a good way to confirm I can at least replicate working code.  I'm just trying to `echo "123"` to the page, so I tried eliminating the directories for forms, models and some of the views from the new module.

Is there some way to see what route I'm really looking for and what routes I defined?  I know CI actually created a log file I was able to check.  It was kind of like Apache logs but specific to framework functionality.

I'd like to post some of my code so someone could point out the mistake I am making and possibly explain why it is wrong.  I tried paying close attention to case since different variations of the word `album` are used throughout the tutorial and I'm not 100% sure which ones are supposed to match up with what just yet.  I'm trying to make it work for `http://www.example.com/productbriefs`.

**Folder Structure**

[image: Folder Structure]

**module.config.php:**

```
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Productbriefs\Controller\Productbriefs' => 'Productbriefs\Controller\ProductbriefsController',
    ),
),

// The following section is new and should be added to your file
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'productbriefs' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/productbriefs',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Productbriefs\Controller\Productbriefs',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'productbriefs' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

);

**ProductbriefsController.php**

```
namespace Productbriefs\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class ProductbriefsController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "123";
    }
}
```

**Module.php**

```
namespace Productbriefs;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `Productbriefs` module to the array in `application.config.php`?

Comment: Thank you, that was it.  I knew it was something simple. If you post an answer I'll accept it.  I believe I understand the relationships between most  of the elements of these 3 files.  The only portion I don't know the function of is the `controllers->invokables` array in module.config.php.  Is this basically just setting up an alias to my various controllers so I don't have to append `Controller` onto every call? (IE: `Productbriefs` instead of `ProductbriefsController`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you need to add `Productbriefs` to the module array in `application.config.php` or the module (including its configuration) will not be loaded.

To answer your second question, the controller manager needs to know how to load the controller classes your application uses. An 'invokable' is a class that can be instantiated without needing any arguments passed to it, so by adding controllers to that array you're telling the controller manager that it can instantiate that class simply by doing `$controller = new Productbriefs\Controller\ProductbriefsController()`. The key for the array is an alias, yes. This can be anything, although the ZF convention is to use the fully qualified name of the class but omit the 'Controller' suffix from the end. When you refer to controllers in your routing config you use these aliases.